# iOS client - GraphQL server file upload only receive a string

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, upload, apollo

Okay, so I need to upload an image from my iOS device to my NestJS GraphQL server.

This is the mutation:

```
createSellerProfile(seller: SellerInput, userId: ID!, uploads: Upload): Seller
```

iOS Client's .graphql file:

```
mutation createSellerProfile($seller: SellerInput, $userId: ID!, $uploads: Upload) {
    createSellerProfile (seller: $seller, userId: $userId, uploads: $uploads) {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
    }
}
```

The upload request:

```
let avaimg = avatarImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)

let file = GraphQLFile(fieldName: "avatar", originalName: "avatar", mimeType: "image/jpeg", data: avaimg)
        
let sellerData = SellerInput(firstName: "phuong", lastName: "nguyen", description: "Hello, this is Phuong. I am freelance web developer")
        
Network.shared.apollo.upload(operation: CreateSellerProfileMutation(seller: sellerData, 
userId: "4d146299-a219-4bde-9874-bed936dda129", uploads: "avatar"), files: [file]) {
       res in
       switch (res) {
       case .success(let graphQLResult):
            print("success")
       case .failure(let error):
            print("error: \(error)")
       }
}
```

But on my NestJS server, I only receive a single string "avatar" for my uploads field instead of file content.
Please help me out, thank you.

Comment: Are you find any solution?

Comment: @user673482 yea, I found a solution. I needed to change "avatar" to "uploads"
the client's code:
`Network.shared.apollo.upload(operation: CreateSellerProfileMutation(seller: sellerData, 
userId: "4d146299-a219-4bde-9874-bed936dda129", uploads: "uploads"), files: [file])`

Comment: you can read our discussion here: https://community.apollographql.com/t/ios-client-cannot-upload-file-to-back-end-server/1128/5